# Use vs Using: preferred style?

Tags: .net, f#

In F#, `use` seems more readable to me, but `using` is more declarative in nature. Is there a general rule of thumb for which to favor in source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I generally prefer `use`. The `using` function has been in the libraries in the times when `use` did not exist, so some older F# examples might use `using` even in cases when the `use` keyword would make more sense.

The `using` function might still make sense when you want to specify the scope more explicitly:

```
using (new StreamWriter(..)) (fun sw -> 
  sw.Write("hi"))
printfn "Something more here"
```

But even this can be written using `use`:

```
( use sw = new StreamWriter(..)
  sw.Write("hi") )
printfn "Something more here"
```

Another nice thing about the `use` keyword is that you can use it inside sequence expressions (when generating collections e.g. from file content) and in asynchronous workflows (to manage connections allocated during network communication).